# Convert image contours to polar coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to categorize the type of jigsaw puzzle pieces (number of heads, if it is a border or a corner...) by analyzing their contours.

The approach I'm trying to follow is analyzing this type of plot (from [this](https://nithyanandabhat.weebly.com/uploads/4/5/6/1/45617813/project_report-jigsaw-puzzle.pdf) paper) that "unwinds" the cartesian coordinates of the contours of the puzzle piece by converting it to polar coordinates; however I'm not able to replicate it.

[image: polar plot of puzzle pieces coordinates]

I've tried with:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cart2pol(x, y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    return(rho, phi)

# load image and find contours
img = cv2.imread("example.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# get contour points in polar coordinates
rhos = []
for i in range(len(contours[0])):
    x, y = contours[0][i][0]
    rho, _ = cart2pol(x, y)
    rhos.append(rho)

plt.show()
plt.plot(rhos)
```

but that produces a different plot, like this:

[image: plot of distance by center]

from this image:

[image: jigsaw puzzle piece]

Trying this on other images I can see how the peaks and valleys correspond to heads and holes of the pieces, but I would like a plot (not properly a function from what I see) like the one above. Can you help me to get that?

Comment: carToPolar is for vectors not an image. Use linearPolar. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaa38a6884ac8b6e0b9bed47939b5362f3

Comment: Correction: That one is deprecated. Use warpPolar. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga49481ab24fdaa0ffa4d3e63d14c0d5e4

Comment: move the origin into the piece (subtract the center). then the values will make sense. you don't need to warp the whole picture. just apply the calculation to the contour points. and you can't just discard the angle! you need it too!

Comment: @fmw42 thanks a lot. Maybe I've approached it the wrong way. Once I converted an image to polar, hence getting something like the desired output but still an image, how can I do some peak analysis on it?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks! applying cart2pol to my x and y - center coordinates leads to peaks that better represent features of the piece (even if it is still not that kind of hoped output). However I still don't get how should I use phi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the center of the tile:

```py
M = cv2.moments(contours[0])
cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
```

Calculate the vectors from the center to the points on the contour and convert the vectors to polar coordinates:

```py
ds, phis = [], []
for i in range(len(contours[0])):
    x, y = contours[0][i][0]
    d, rho = cart2pol(x-cx, y-cy)
    ds.append(d)
    phis.append(rho)
```

Plot the polar coordinates with angle on the x-axis and distance on the y-axis:

```py
plt.plot(phis, ds)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import os
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def cart2pol(x, y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    return (rho, phi)

img = cv2.imread('opencv_so_9_example.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

M = cv2.moments(contours[0])
cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

polar = [cart2pol(c[0][0] - cx, c[0][1] - cy) for c in contours[0][:]]
max_i = polar.index(max(polar, key = lambda x: x[1]))
polar = polar[max_i:] + polar[:max_i]
ds, phis = zip(*polar)

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 3)     
plt.plot(phis, ds)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also do this with the binary image and warpPolar in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# read image
img = cv2.imread('puzzle.png')
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

 # get non-zero points (i.e. white)
points = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh.transpose() > 0))

# get centroid
M = cv2.moments(points)
cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]) 

# compute maxradius = furthest corner - center
maxrad = math.sqrt( (wd-cx)*(wd-cx) + (ht-cy)*(ht-cy) )

# convert to polar image relative to centroid
polar1 = cv2.warpPolar(thresh, (ht,wd), (cx,cy), maxrad, cv2.INTER_CUBIC+cv2.WARP_POLAR_LINEAR+cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)

# rotate 270 clocwise
polar2 = cv2.rotate(polar1, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
ht, wd = polar2.shape[:2]

# save image
cv2.imwrite('puzzle_polar1.png',polar1)
cv2.imwrite('puzzle_polar2.png',polar2)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("polar1", polar1)
cv2.imshow("polar2", polar2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]